# HTML video loop re-downloads video file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, http, amazon-s3

I have an HTML5 video that is rather large. I'm also using Chrome. The video element has the `loop` attribute but each time the video "loops", the browser re-downloads the video file. I have set `Cache-Control "max-age=15768000, private"`. However, this does not prevent any extra downloads of the identical file. I am using Amazon S3 to host the file. Also the s3 server responds with the `Accepts Ranges` header which causes the several hundred partial downloads of the file to be requested with the `206` http response code.

Here is my video tag:

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" class="asset current">
    <source src="https://mybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myvideo.mp4">
</video>
```

UPDATE:

It seems that the best solution is to prevent the `Accept Ranges` header from being sent with the original response and instead use a 200 http response code. How can this be achieved so that the video is fully cached through an `.htaccess` file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is the video, and how often will it loop?  Another way to handle this is with a service worker.

Comment: @Brad It's 900mb and it loops infinitely.

Comment: Have you checked the cache size in the browser?

Comment: How did you know that the browser re-download the file? Do you have the same problem when you play the file from a local source (as oppose to amazon s3). Are you playing the file in a single page or does it exist in DOM?

Comment: @KalimahApps I watched it redownload via dev tools, it never hits the cache. And yes, I have the same problem no matter where it's hosted (my server or s3). It exists in the DOM.

Comment: @DavidBradshaw I did attempt to check this but it seems that the cache is set as percentage of the HDD size so I would think there would be plenty of space.

Comment: Did you try reencoding your video? Does the same happen with a webm version of your video?

Comment: @Kaiido Please send me your Venmo username... I didn't know that `webm` would actually reduce the file size so drastically which caused this to work. It looks like chrome just simply won't cache large files like my mp4. Please add this as the answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure what's the real issue you are facing.

It could be that Chrome has a max-size limit to what they'd cache, and if it the case, then not using Range-Requests wouldn't solve anything.

An other possible explanation is that **caching media** is not really a simple task.
Without seeing your file it's hard to tell for sure in which case you are, but you have to understand that to play a media, the browser doesn't need to fetch the whole file.
For instance, you can very well play a video file in an <audio> element, since the video stream won't be used, a browser could very well omit it completely and download only the audio stream. Not sure if any does, but they could. Most media formats do physically separate audio and video streams in the file and their byte positions are marked in the metadata.
They could certainly cache the Range-Requests they perform, but I think it's still quite rare they do.

But as tempting it might be to disable Range-Requests, you've to know that some browsers (Safari) will not play your media if your server doesn't allow Range-Requests.
So even then, it's probably not what you want.

---

The first thing you may want to try is to optimize your video for web usage. Instead of mp4, serve a webm file. These will generally take less space for the same quality and maybe you'll avoid the *max-size limitation*.

If the resulting file is still too big, then a dirty solution would be to use a MediaSource so that the file is kept in memory and you need to fetch it only once.

In the following example, the file will be fetched entirely only once, by chunks of 1MB, streamed by the MediaSource as it's being fetched and then only the data in memory will be used for looping plays:

```js
document.getElementById('streamVid').onclick = e => (async () => {

const url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm.360p.webm';
// you must know the mimeType of your video before hand.
const type = 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"';
if( !MediaSource.isTypeSupported( type ) ) {
  throw 'Unsupported';
}

const source = new MediaSource();
source.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
document.getElementById('out').src = URL.createObjectURL( source );

// async generator Range-Fetcher
async function* fetchRanges( url, chunk_size = 1024 * 1024 ) {
  let chunk = new ArrayBuffer(1);
  let cursor = 0;
  while( chunk.byteLength ) {
    const resp = await fetch( url, {
      method: "get",
        headers: { "Range": "bytes=" + cursor + "-" + ( cursor += chunk_size ) }
      }
    )
    chunk = resp.ok && await resp.arrayBuffer();
    cursor++; // add one byte for next iteration, Ranges are inclusive
    yield chunk;
  }
}
// set up our MediaSource
async function sourceOpen() {
  const buffer = source.addSourceBuffer( type );
  buffer.mode = "sequence";
  // waiting forward to appendAsync...
  const appendBuffer = ( chunk ) => {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      buffer.addEventListener( 'update', resolve, { once: true } );
      buffer.appendBuffer( chunk );
    } );
  }
  // while our RangeFetcher is running
  for await ( const chunk of fetchRanges(url) ) {
    if( chunk ) { // append to our MediaSource
      await appendBuffer( chunk );
    }
    else { // when done
      source.endOfStream();
    }
  }
}
})().catch( console.error );
```

```html
<button id="streamVid">stream video</button>
<video id="out" controls muted autoplay loop></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google chrome has a limit to the size of it's file catch. In this case my previous answer would not work. You should use something like [file-compressor](https://www.youcompress.com/) this resource may be able to compress the file enough that it makes the file cache eligible. The webbrowser can have a new cache size manually set however this is not doable if the end user has not designated their cache to agree with the space required to hold the long video.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility that people that got here are facing - the dev-tool has a "Disable Cache" Option under Network tab. When enabled (meaning cache is disabled) the browser probably doesn't cache the videos, hence needs to download them again.
[disable cache from network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xilr.png)